# Permission denied creating user via HTTP api grafana

Tags: grafana

I am trying to create new user using grafana HTTP rest api:

I am doing HTTP post to `https://adminTest:adminTest@grafanaUrl:8086/api/admin/users` with body:

```
{
  "name":"User",
  "email":"user@graf.com",
  "login":"user",
  "password":"userpassword"
}
```

However i get:

```
{
    "message": "Permission denied"
}
```

What are the right steps to create user with HTTP api?  The `adminTest` account is admin account in grafana,

Comment: Is the `adminTest` account only `admin` or `Grafana admin` as well? It needs to be the latter.

Comment: @dnnshssm i see! that may be the problem. Could you hint me where can i check it/how can i make `testUser` grafana admin ?

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer

Answer (score 3):

To use the [HTTP Admin API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/admin/#admin-api), a user has to be a [Grafana server admin](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/administration/roles-and-permissions/#grafana-server-administrators). The term Grafana admin can therefore be a bit misleading.

To make a user a Grafana server admin, you have to be one yourself. From the [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/administration/user-management/server-user-management/assign-remove-server-admin-privileges/#assign-or-remove-grafana-server-administrator-privileges):

> To assign or remove Grafana administrator privileges:
>
> 1. Sign in to Grafana as a server administrator.
> 2. Hover your cursor over the Server Admin (shield) icon until a menu appears, and click Users.
> 3. Click a user.
> 4. In the Grafana Admin section, click Change.
> 5. Click Yes or No, depending on whether or not you want this user to have the Grafana server administrator role.
> 6. Click Change.